# Git файл одинаковый для всех веток

Tags: git-branch

Добрый день!
Подскажите, как сделать так в git чтобы один файл был всегда одинаковым во всех ветках.
То есть, например, есть  во всех ветках 2 файла. Один файл в во всех ветках разный, а другой должен быть одинаковым для всех. И любое его изменение меняло его во всех ветках.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21459976/4827341

Answer (score 0):

> как сделать так в git чтобы один файл был всегда одинаковым во всех ветках

Если кратко, то **никак**.
Если подробнее, то начнем с небольшой теории.
[**Ветка**](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%3F) в git - это **легковесный подвижный указатель** на один из этих коммитов. Т.е. каждая ветка указывает на состояние репозитория в определенный момент времени. Если мы имеем 2 ветки (одна получена из другой), то на момент создания 2й ветки они ссылаются на один коммит (= одно состояние репозитория) и все файлы одинаковы. В дальнейшем каждый коммит в одной из веток будет указывать на новое состояние репозитория и другая ветка никакого отношения к нему (этому состоянию) не имеет. Соответственно, каждый исходный файл гарантированно остается одинаковым в обоих ветках только до того момента, когда не будет коммита, затрагивающего этот файл, в любой из веток. После любого изменения этого файла необходимо "синхронизировать" изменения в другую ветку (с помощью `git merge`).

Кратко подытожим по вашей задаче: изначально оба файла одинаковы в обоих ветках, затем при изменении файла, который вы хотите поддерживать одинаковым во всех ветках, вам нужно переносить изменения самостоятельно.

**PS**: для чего вы это делаете? Возможно, вам этого и не требуется) Иначе вы пытаетесь бороться с помощью git-а с его же функционалом (с версионностью файлов)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Нужно это как раз для примера. У нас есть набор конфигураций. конфигурация для каждого сервера меняется в одном файле. А во втором файле грубо говоря некий код который использует первый файл для применения конфигурации. Каждая группа серверов использует отдельную ветку. Время от времени файл номер два совершенствуется. Возможно нужно что-то поменять идеологически. Но на первый взгляд хотелось бы просто скачать на сервер файлы репозитория и сразу чтобы была готовая конфигурация.

Comment: Идея понятна. Видимо, все таки вам придется мержить изменения в каждую ветку вручную.